# Difference between two dates and getting result in timestamp

Tags: oracle

I´m trying to calculate the difference between two dates in Oracle and getting the result as a TimeStamp. This is the easiest thing to do in SQL Server, but it seems that Oracle does not have a easy way to solve this. I refuse to believe that I have to write that much code to get what I need. Can someone tell me if there is a easier way to get that difference?:

```
SELECT TO_CHAR(EXTRACT(HOUR FROM NUMTODSINTERVAL(enddate-startdate, 'DAY')), 'FM00')
   || ':' ||
 TO_CHAR(EXTRACT(MINUTE FROM NUMTODSINTERVAL(enddate-startdate, 'DAY')), 'FM00')
   || ':' ||
 TO_CHAR(EXTRACT(SECOND FROM NUMTODSINTERVAL(enddate-startdate, 'DAY')), 'FM00')
```

I need the result be something like:

```
enddate = '2017-03-01 17:30:00'
startdate = '2017-03-01 10:00:00'

difference: 07:30:00
```

Comment: A difference between two dates *isn't* a timestamp though... what *timestamp* do you think the difference between January 1st 2001 and February 3rd 2005 would be?

Comment: Perhaps "timestamp" means something different in SQL Server; with the concepts as defined in Oracle, the requirement itself is nonsensical. The difference between two dates is a number (expressed in days). A "number of days" is not a timestamp, no matter how you try to write code.

Comment: I understand what you tell me. But is there a easy way to get what I´m trying? In my case, the enddate is always greater than the startdate

Comment: What is it that you are trying? If you can explain it, we may be able to help you. What does the desired output look like?

Comment: I edited the question and added an example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Substract the two dates. Add the result to the current date (without any time component, trunc(sysdate)) and show only the time.

```
select to_char(trunc(sysdate) + (to_date('2017-03-01 17:30:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') -
                                 to_date('2017-03-01 10:00:00', 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS'))
              ,'HH24:MI:SS')
  from dual
```

Comment: Works only when difference < 24 hours I suppose.